# Crystal - suppress a record, if subreport brings back information

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to write a report which shows all customers who have placed an order within a time scale AND who don't have a current order open.

I have the closed order records showing in the main report, then the subreport is currently searching for any open orders and if there is one it popuplates in.

How do I prevent those who have current open orders from showing in the main report?

*The only way to show if an order is open or closed is whether it has a closed date entered

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code by editing your question?

Comment: do you have any field that tells you the order is open or closed?

Comment: how do you decide whether a order is open or not?

Comment: There isn't a field that says if an order is open or closed, just the order start date and end date.